# Receive latest questions with certain tag

Tags: support, api, questions

I'm creating a simple notification application to inform me about latest questions with defined tags. For example, my tags are `python` and `django`.
I want to see the latest asked question with those.
Which API URL should I use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [`/questions`](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/questions), it provides an option to filter on tags. You'll also need to set the `sort` parameter to `creation` instead of the default, `activity`.

This will be the URL you're looking for: https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions?order=desc&sort=creation&tagged=python&site=stackoverflow

You can test it [here](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/questions#order=desc&sort=creation&tagged=python&filter=default&site=stackoverflow&run=true), the first question it gave me was [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45461544/custom-django-management-commands-broken-on-windows) which was posted just a minute before.

Comment: Thanks @Arulkumar. It's strange that http://api.stackexchange.com isn't automatically redirected to HTTPS.

Comment: Yes, like http://area51.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Arulkumar I've posted a [question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/299181/295232) (read: answer) on Meta SE about that.